# How to convert Clip-space gl_Position to something you can write to a color buffer (0-1)

Tags: opengl, glsl

"How do I convert clip-space gl_Position to a valid depth?"
I have a vertex shader that calculates a vertex position

```
//Do stuff
gl_Position = stuff;
```

then in my fragment shader I want to use the value of stuff.z and write it to a color buffer. How?!?!

Answer (score -2):

(ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear)
where Janear is the near clip plane and jafar is the far clip plane

ourdepth is the value output as gl_Position.z in the vertex shader

This is infinitely useful for people trying to do shadowmapping

Here is my example code (sorry if it is messy)

```
#version 330

//INITIAL_OPAQUE.VS
//(C) Geklmin 2018




layout( location = 0 ) in vec3 vPosition;
layout( location = 1 ) in vec2 intexcoord;
layout( location = 2 ) in vec3 Normal;
layout( location = 3 ) in vec3 VertexColor;

out vec2 texcoord;
out vec3 normout;
flat out vec3 flatnormout;
out vec3 Smooth_Vert_Color;
out vec3 ND_out;
out vec2 window_size;
flat out vec3 Flat_Vert_Color;
out vec3 vert_to_camera;
out float ourdepth;

vec3 worldpos; //Position of the fragment in the world!

uniform float windowsize_x;
uniform float windowsize_y;
uniform mat4 World2Camera; //the world to camera transform. I figure this is faster than calculating MVP seperately per vertex.
uniform mat4 Model2World; //Model->World
uniform uint renderflags;
uniform vec3 CameraPos;
void
main()
{
    window_size = vec2(windowsize_x, windowsize_y);
    //The position of this vertex in the world coordinate system.
    worldpos = (Model2World * vec4(vPosition,1.0)).xyz;
    vec4 big_gay = World2Camera * Model2World * vec4(vPosition,1.0);
    texcoord = intexcoord; //this is faster
    gl_Position = big_gay;
    ourdepth = big_gay.z; //Depth
    normout = (Model2World * vec4(Normal, 0.0)).xyz;
    flatnormout = normout;
    ND_out = big_gay.xyz;
    Smooth_Vert_Color = VertexColor;
    Flat_Vert_Color = VertexColor;

    vert_to_camera = CameraPos  - worldpos;
}
```

and my fragment shader:

```
#version 330
// #extension GL_ARB_conservative_depth : enable
// out vec4 fColor[2];
// INITIAL_OPAQUE.FS
// (C) Geklmin 2018
// layout (depth_greater) out float gl_FragDepth;
// ^ should probably re-enable that later

//List of flags. Some of these are no longer implemented, they caused too much of a performance problem. I do not recommend you enable them.
const uint GK_RENDER = uint(1); // Do we render it? This is perhaps the most important flag.
const uint GK_TEXTURED = uint(2); // Do we texture it? if disabled, only the texture will be used. if both this and colored are disabled, the object will be black.
const uint GK_COLORED = uint(4);// Do we color it? if disabled, only the texture will be used. if both this and textured are disabled, the object will be black.
const uint GK_FLAT_NORMAL = uint(8); // Do we use flat normals? If this is set, then the normals output to the fragment shader in the initial opaque pass will use the flat layout qualifier. 
const uint GK_FLAT_COLOR = uint(16); // Do we render flat colors? the final, provoking vertex will be used as the color for the entire triangle.
const uint GK_COLOR_IS_BASE = uint(32); //Use the color as the primary. Uses texture as primary if disabled.
const uint GK_TINT = uint(64); //Does secondary add to primary?
const uint GK_DARKEN = uint(128);//Does secondary subtract from primary?
const uint GK_AVERAGE = uint(256);//Do secondary and primary just get averaged?
const uint GK_COLOR_INVERSE = uint(512);//Do we use the inverse of the color?
const uint GK_TEXTURE_INVERSE = uint(1024);//Do we use the inverse of the texture color? DOES NOT invert alpha.
const uint GK_TEXTURE_ALPHA_MULTIPLY = uint(2048);//Do we multiply the color from the texture by the alpha before doing whatever it is we're doing? I do not recommend enabling this and alpha culling, especially if you're trying to create a texture-on-a-flat-color-model effect (Think sega saturn models)
const uint GK_ENABLE_ALPHA_CULLING = uint(4096); //Do we use the texture alpha to cull alpha fragments
const uint GK_TEXTURE_ALPHA_REPLACE_PRIMARY_COLOR = uint(8192); //if the alpha from the texture is <0.5 then the secondary color will replace the primary color.








uniform sampler2D diffuse; //This is actually the texture unit. limit 32. This one happens to be for the literal object's texture.
uniform samplerCube worldaroundme; //This is the cubemap we use for reflections.

in vec2 texcoord;
in vec3 normout;
flat in vec3 flatnormout;
flat in vec3 Flat_Vert_Color;
in vec3 Smooth_Vert_Color;
in vec3 ND_out;
in vec2 window_size;
in vec3 vert_to_camera;
in float ourdepth;
uniform float ambient;
uniform float specreflectivity;
uniform float specdamp;
uniform float emissivity;
uniform float jafar; //The floating-point number you gave to GLM or GLU when you told it to build a perspective matrix, for the far clipping plane
uniform float janear; //The floating-point number you gave to GLM or GLU when you told it to build a perspective matrix, for the near clipping plane

uniform float diffusivity;

vec2 bettertexcoord;
vec4 texture_value;
vec3 color_value;
vec3 primary_color;
vec3 secondary_color;
vec3 finalcolor;
uniform uint renderflags;
vec4 FindNDC() //this fuckin thing!
{
    return vec4((gl_FragCoord.x / window_size.x - 0.5) * 2.0, (gl_FragCoord.y / window_size.y - 0.5) * 2.0, (gl_FragCoord.z - 0.5) * 2.0, 1.0);
}

void main()
{
    bettertexcoord = vec2(texcoord.x, -texcoord.y); //Looks like blender
    vec3 UnitNormal;
    vec3 usefulNormal;
    //Just normalizing our vectors...
    if ((renderflags & GK_FLAT_NORMAL) > uint(0))
    {
        UnitNormal = (normalize(flatnormout) + vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0)) * 0.5;
        usefulNormal = normalize(flatnormout);
    }
    else
    {
        UnitNormal = (normalize(normout) + vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0)) * 0.5;
        usefulNormal = normalize(normout);
    }



    //Texture stuff
    if ((renderflags & GK_TEXTURED) > uint(0))
        texture_value = (texture2D(diffuse, bettertexcoord));
    else
        texture_value = vec4(0.0,0.2,0.0,1.0);


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //UNCOMMENT THIS LINE IF YOU WANT ALPHA CULLING! It will slow down your application, be weary!
    // if ((renderflags & GK_ENABLE_ALPHA_CULLING) > uint(0))
        // if (texture_value.w == 0)
            // discard;
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Color stuff
    if ((renderflags & GK_FLAT_COLOR & GK_COLORED) > uint(0))
    {
            color_value = Flat_Vert_Color;
    } else {
        if ((renderflags & GK_COLORED) > uint(0))
        {
            color_value = Smooth_Vert_Color;
        } else {
            color_value = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        }
    }


    //primary_color and secondary_color stuff

    if ((renderflags & GK_COLOR_IS_BASE) > uint(0))
    {
        primary_color = color_value;
        secondary_color = texture_value.xyz;
    } else {
        primary_color = texture_value.xyz;
        secondary_color = color_value;
    }

     if ((renderflags & GK_TEXTURE_ALPHA_REPLACE_PRIMARY_COLOR) > uint(0))
     {
         //extremely clever programming results in perfect effect...
        primary_color = (primary_color * (1-texture_value.w)) + (texture_value.xyz * texture_value.w);
     } 

    //EQUATION TIME!
    if ((renderflags & GK_TINT) > uint(0))
        finalcolor = primary_color + secondary_color;
    else if ((renderflags & GK_DARKEN) > uint(0))
        finalcolor = primary_color - secondary_color;
    else if ((renderflags & GK_AVERAGE) > uint(0))
        finalcolor = vec3(
        (primary_color.x + secondary_color.x)/2.0,
        (primary_color.y + secondary_color.y)/2.0,
        (primary_color.z + secondary_color.z)/2.0);
    else
        finalcolor = primary_color;



    vec4 ND_Modified = FindNDC();
    ND_Modified = vec4(
    (ND_Modified.x + 1.0) * 0.5,
    (ND_Modified.y + 1.0) * 0.5,
    (ND_Modified.z + 1.0) * 0.5,
    ND_Modified.w);


    // (diffuse component * texture) + specular
    gl_FragData[0] = vec4(finalcolor,specreflectivity);
    //gl_FragData[0] = (vec4(betterdiffuse,1.0) + vec4(ambient,ambient,ambient,1.0)) * vec4(Smooth_Vert_Color,0) + vec4(finalSpecular, 1.0);
    gl_FragData[1] = vec4(UnitNormal,specdamp); //Normals

    //INTENSE DEBUGGING OF FRAG DEPTH
    // if ((ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear) >= 0 && (ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear)<= 1.0)
    // {
        gl_FragData[2] = vec4((ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear), diffusivity, 1.0, emissivity);
    // }
    // else if ((ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear) < 0)
    // {
        // gl_FragData[2] = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    // } else if ((ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear) > 1.0){
        // gl_FragData[2] = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    // }

    //These are unnecessary and should be deleted.
    gl_FragData[3] = vec4(
        ambient,
        specreflectivity,
        specdamp/128.0, //This should give a wide range...
        emissivity
    );
    gl_FragData[4] = vec4(texture(worldaroundme,reflect(-vert_to_camera, usefulNormal)).xyz, 0); //To be used for cubemap reflections
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using a separate varying `ourdepth` and then doing `(ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear)`, if `(gl_FragCoord.z - 0.5) * 2.0` does the same thing? And you already have the second thing in your code, just in a different place.

Comment: It doesn't actually work. I actually removed this feature later.

Comment: gl_FragCoord.z is actually the same for every pixel on the screen